# A contactor switches 800 amps from two 26 volt batteries in series in a resistive circuit. Can I use a mosfet

Tags: current, switching

The batteries are Lithium Iron Phosphate 26 volts each. There is no inductive or capacative load. The gating circuit should use either the 26 volts or the 52 volts. The switch will operate 8 times per minute. The time from zero current to full on is not critical, nor is the time from full on to zero. Is this possible? can anyone suggest a suitable gate circuit?

Comment: uff, 800 A at 26 V: what is your load? It has to have 32 mΩ resistance only, i.e. be a big bar of copper or similar. And it needs to be shaped pretty specifically to not have a non-negligible inductance at such a high current.

Comment: Hi Harry, 26V for a LiPo cell is a bit high on the, these two batteries must be composed from several cells. 6~8 in series, 10 strings in parallel? Too much guessing, I'm tempted to vote for closure. It would be good to add much more context to your question, perhaps you have datasheets for the batteries? Also filling some info on your profile may help us understand the context.

Comment: At 26V @ 800A, let's say half way is 13V × 400A = 5200W, your switching time is pretty critical.

Comment: I imagine that at 800A, you are going to see the effects of any parasitic inductance rather strongly.

Comment: @jippie [LiFePO4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_iron_phosphate_battery) and [LiPo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_polymer_battery) batteries are completely different. 26V would be eight 3.25V nominal LiFePO4 cells, and there is an example shown on the Wiki page of a [700A rated battery setup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_iron_phosphate_battery#/media/File:Lithium_Iron_Phosphate_LiFePO4_Cells_700Ah_in_Parallel_and_Series_and_Busbar_-_1.jpg).

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb (not really), and guess that your 26V battery is composed of multiple strings of cells in parallel. How many such strings do you have in parallel? The obvious approach is to provide a MOSFET for each string.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have 800 A driven by 26 V, then that implies that your load, including whatever you use as switch, has only 32 mΩ resistance.

That will most definitely be a challenge to do with a MOSFET as such a low voltage.

I doubt this is physically possible, however, for a different reason: your batteries source impedance needs to be significantly lower than that. And such batteries do, to my knowledge, not exist.

Comment: I’m thinking an array of parallel MOSFETs and copper bus bars soldered to the PCB.

Comment: @winny agreed, but reading the title: it's literally *two* (as in: 2, the integer after 1) batteries sourcing 800 A. Something isn't quite right with the overall concept.

Comment: Little context in the question, empty user profile, so we have no clue what context to see this question in.

Comment: 26V for a LiPo cell is a bit high on the, these two batteries must be composed from several cells. 6~8 in series, 10 strings in parallel? Too much guessing, I'm tempted to vote for closure.

Comment: @jippie I was assuming the series, yes, but you get the series series resistances, too, and you need to end up with << 32 mΩ, which would be lower than a single cell has, as far as I know todays' batteries. So, that would be quite a lot of cell strings in parallel, at which you start wondering about BMSes, and it becomes even more unlikely that OP just forgot to mention that although they thought this through.

Comment: You are right @MarcusMüller, I didn't take the 32mΩ in consideration for my guestimate, I was just thinking max 20C or so for a convenient max discharge current. Although I may have made a small error in my calculation there :-) factor two or so.

Comment: There is an example shown on the Wiki page of a [700A rated battery setup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_iron_phosphate_battery#/media/File:Lithium_Iron_Phosphate_LiFePO4_Cells_700Ah_in_Parallel_and_Series_and_Busbar_-_1.jpg), so 800A from such a LiFePO4 setup is not farfetched. Trying to switch that much current at DC on the other hand would be an interesting setup to say the least.

Comment: Both batteries are nominally 26 volts, they are off the shelf aircraft starter batteries. I have them connected in series giving a terminal voltage of +-56 volts. The output is used to create an arc between two electrodes. The duration of the arc is 300 mill secs and the cables connecting the electrodes are designed to limit the current to about 800 amps. I have the system running with great results, but would like to go Mosfet rather than mechanical contactor. The current is  comfortabley within the battery specs.

Comment: ah nice! Didn't know that was a thing! Cool, I've learned something today. @winny is right then, a not-too-small array of MOSFETs might well do that. Make sure to have a low-impedance high-drive way of switching them on and off; the waste power during transition might be substantial, and thus the heating.

Comment: @Harry, you should edit that information into your question rather than bury it down here. Context usually helps in answering a question and showing that you understand what you're doing will encourage better answers.

Answer (score 2):

At the peak power dissipation point, where I = Imax/2 and where V = Vmax/2,
the dissipation will be 400 amp * 26v  = 10,000 watts.

In the absence of any Safe Operating Area SOA diagram, let us compute a SOA pulse_time_power limit.

Assume we are willing to heat up the silicon die by 10 ° C.

Assume the volume of the silicon die is 3mm By 3mm By 0.1mm (100 microns thick).
The volume is 3,000 * 3,000 * 100 == 900,000,000 cubic microns.

The thermal capacity of silicon is 1.6 picoJoules per degree C per cubic micron.

We have a Billion cubic microns.

We'll assume a vertical FET, thus the heat is generated somewhat uniformly throughout the thickness of the silicon (some FETs have lateral current flow, and those FETs generate heat only near the surface, so heating is much more localized and dangerous).

Now the math.

Our specific heat --- 1.6 picoJoule/degC/cubic_micron --- scaled by 1 Billion cubic microns, tells us

1.6 milliJoules per degree C

Given we think we can tolerate 10 degree C rise, the heat pulse (of switching) can be 16 milliJoules.

How fast must we switch?

0.016 joules / 10,000 joules/second

Time = 1.6 microsecond <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

What does this mean, so far as inductive bounce/kickback?

V = L * di/dT = 1uH (about a meter of wire) * 800 amps / 1.6uS

and the uH cancel the uS, so we have

800/1.6 = 500 volts inductive kick.

Thus part of the design task is to implement a very low inductance 800 amp power distribution system.